# How to use javascript to put a can't remove char at input start

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put a colon at the start of input, like this:
[image]

It can't be delete.
I think can use a label to put it, then use css to position it, right?
How to use javascript to do it?
By the way, I use shift+: to show this input, but when I use script to focus it, the colon auto input into, how to remove?

Comment: May be you should try css pseudo-elements , like `:before` ?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done in many ways, just in pure CSS without even disturbing Javascript. **Background images** and **pseudo elements** come to my mind.

I've played around and came out with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5DZP/

Notice that the input element must be wrapped in a div (or any other *container* element) otherwise `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements won't apply.

Comment: **+1** for using `absolute` in the `:before` selector :)

Comment: how about the last question?

Comment: I don't understand it. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VBEmA/)**

You can do this with multiple layers and positioning:

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="input" type="text" />
    <div id="colon">:</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}

#input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#colon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```